# Should we split the challah tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

Currently, there's one [challah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challah) tag, which covers mostly questions about the bread used at Shabbat meals, but also with one question about the actual Mitzva of separating challah.

Should we split this tag up into a [separating-challah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separating-challah) and a [challah-shabbat-bread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challah-shabbat-bread) (or something), which would be synonymized with the just-created [lechem-mishneh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lechem-mishneh)?

Comment: +1 for לחם חוקים!

Comment: Interesting idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. (This makes it 30 chars.)

Comment: Agreed. They are two different topics, similar in name only. Don't forget to account for potential questions about (non-_shabas_) ritual loaves brought with _karbanos_.

Comment: Done (15 chars)

Comment: -1, Challah bread is a part of Jewish Life (minhag on shabbat, some of the holidays) but does not necessarily have halakhic significance.  Any loaf or roll of bread can be used for lechem mishneh.

Comment: @Adam, that's certainly true. Do you not think we should have a tag for _lechem mishne_ at all, though, or are you just arguing against the name [tag:challah-shabbat-bread] for it?

Comment: @msh210 - There are certain minhagim revolving around challah that are meant to be a zecher to the manna, such as having two of them on shabbat, as well as having the top and bottom layer symbolizing how the manna came in a "package" with dew, etc.  Also, how could you forget people who say the verse einei kol eilecha yesabeiru v'atah nosein lahem es ochlam b'ito prior to birkas hamotzi, symbolizing that all food is like the manna and comes from the Heavens (contrast: hamotzi lechem min HAARETZ).  Lechem mishneh is one of those things that helps us remind that it is zecher laman.